# Constraints on the substituent when solving the indefinite integral using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider we need to find indefinite integral of $\sqrt{(a^2 - x^2)}$ first we assume x = $a\sin\theta$ and then the procedure as follows : \begin{array}{l}
x=a \sin \theta\\
\int \sqrt{a^{2}-a^{2} \sin ^{2} \theta} a \cos \theta d \theta\\
\Rightarrow \int_{0} \sqrt{a^{2} \cos ^{2} \theta}(a \cos \theta) d \theta\\
\Rightarrow \int\left|a^{2}|| \cos \theta \mid a \cos \theta d \theta\right.\\ \tag{1}
                              \int(a \cos \theta)(a \cos \theta) d \theta\\
\Rightarrow \int a^{2} \cos ^{2} \theta d \theta\\
a^{2} \int\left[\frac{1+\cos 2 \theta}{2}\right] d \theta\\
\Rightarrow a^{2}\left[\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}\right]  \$tag{2}$
\end{array}.

> My query is regarding the steps 1 , 2 whats the reason of taking modulus as +costheta only ? I think for "a" we can say from starting a>0 . So its okay for that . Now finally after we get last step when we now reverse the substitution $x/a = sin\theta$ , applying arc sin both sides we get arcsin $sin\theta  = arcsin(x/a)$ , now its possible that theta might not lie now in range of arcsin so how to deal with that ? Many books just dont mention anything about this and just cancel sin to say its just theta . But whats the actual reason for that ? And when we convert this $sin\theta$ to $sin2\theta$ for final answer in terms of x how to decide the sign in +-$√(1-sin^2\theta)$ when substituting value for $cos\theta$ in $2sin\theta.cos\theta$ = $sin2\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind the domains of your functions. $\sqrt{a^2- x^2}$ is only defined on $-a \le x \le a$ anyways, so we can safely say that $|x/a| \le 1$ for the domain of our antiderivative. The sign of $\cos\theta$ is also not a concern, because the domain of $\theta$ is $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, and $\cos\theta > 0$ for all $\theta$ in this domain.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out , i totally forgot about that earlier